# Can someone tell me if my bike is rare?

Tags: folding-bicycle

I have had this bike for a while, it was a gift to my mother from my grandfather. Neither of us have been able to find it online or anything. On the frame it says "Swift-20M Folding Bike Patanta. It was made in China and offers 6 speeds. If anyone knows what it is, can you tell me how much it is worth, if anything at all?

[image: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVjsL.jpg)]

Comment: I can't say how "rare" it is.  It's not especially old, and the componentry is not especially high quality.  It does look like a halfway decent bike, however, for tooling around town.

Comment: It all depends how long the bike was cooked for, and at what temperature.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry it doesn't look like anything particularly special.

The rear wheel is very likely a freewheel as opposed to a more modern cassette and freehub.  That means you're unlikely to find a replacement that has much bigger or smaller gears, so its hard to ride up steep grades, and its easy to spin out riding fast in a tailwind.

Fortunately it appears to have normal plastic platform pedals.  Many Chinese folding bikes have folding pedals, which are okay for gentle riding.  You shouldn't stand on folding pedals, and they have a disconcerting flex under load.

The frame looks like steel, confirm that with a magnet.

The hinge clamps look to be threadded, which is a bit more reassuring than a bifold clamp like some bikes have.

In short it looks like a loverly bike, ride it and enjoy it, and you can use busses or trains or cars for part of your journey, and then ride the last bit.

Comment: I had a 20"  folder with similar gearing, and ended up rebuilding the wheel rim/spokes onto an 8 speed freehub, then usingn an 11-34 block.  That helped, but I still spun out at 135 RPM, and medium hills were slow and torturous.  So I changed the single crank for a triple, and now have 15.4 to 85 gear inches.